# Perl RE to check string values separated by comma

Tags: regex, perl

How do I check `$message` has value strictly following the format `CRs: <numbers separated by comma and a space>`

```
 e.g:
 #good
 CRs: 1234, 2345, 6789 
 CRs: 54321

 #bad ones:
 CRs: 1234 2345 6789
 CRs: 1234 , 2345 , 6789
 CRs: 1234,2345,6789
```

I have an incomplete RE as below:

```
if ($message !~ m/CRs:\s+\d+,?/) {
      print "ERROR";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^CRs:\s+\d+(?:,\s+\d+)*$
```

Use anchors to make a string match.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/16

Comment: Is the `?:` in the grouping necessary?

Comment: @stevesliva Not really of u r just validating

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for repetition:

```
...
if ( $message !~ m/^CRs:\s+\d+(?:,\s+\d+)*$/ ) {
  print "ERROR";
}
...
```

`*` after the end of the non-capturing group means to match zero or more times

You can also use anchors `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) to ensure that you aren't getting a partial match. I.e. `123, 456, 789 aaaaaa` would be valid without the end of line anchor.